# Winform freezes when I try to close it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have following code

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     Close();
} // btnClose_Click
```

After running the close winforms function the application freezes. Any idea why it can happen?

I use .net 2.0 and i run under Windows 7 vs2005

EDIT:

After I pressed pause in the debugger I came to

```
private void MainForm_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  // GUI
  if (FScannerThread_Running)
  {
    FScannerThread_Running = false;
    FScannerThread.Join();
  }
}
```

And it stacked in `FScannerThread.Join();` any idea how i can kill it ?

Comment: With only this code, it's impossible to tell what happens. Can you explain further what else there is?

Comment: There has to be more code than this.  This would work fine in isolation.

Comment: Do you have anything happening in the `Form_Closing` or `Form_Closed` events ?

Comment: Do you just want to close the window or do you want to quit your app as well?

Comment: @Josefvz , I just want to exit the application

Comment: @Night Walker . Then call `Application.Exit();` like Darren Young suggested. It's a blocking thread so even if there are other threads it will get called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `bool Thread.Join(int milliseconds)` overload, and if the result is false, `Abort()` your thread.

```
private void MainForm_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // GUI
    if (FScannerThread_Running)
    {
        FScannerThread_Running = false;
        if (!FScannerThread.Join(1000)) // Give the thread 1 sec to stop
        {
            FScanner.Abort();
        }    
    }
}
```

Note that you should catch `ThreadAbortException` in your thread in order to end it gracefully (if you have something to release for instance).

Answer (score 4):

When it is freezed, call pause (Break all) in the debug menu - you'll see where diferent threads of your app could hang up.
The platform here does not matter. Sometimes that can happen if you have multithreaded app and in some thread the state was corrupted or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's either

1. Something you do in either the
   `FormClosing` or `FormClosed` events
2. Another thread that's still running

In your case it's both :)

Ideally, and if possible, rewrite the thread method to properly take abortion into account (for example by using one of the synchronization primitives). If not, you could use the `Abort` method of the `Thread` instance, but it's not the recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

If in the close function, you simply want to exit the app, you can just substitute it for

```
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: `Application.Exit();` Is a blocking thread so even if there are other threads running your app should exit properly